# Is this the 'Weaver's Knot'?

Tags: knots, himmeli

I'm trying to remember a knot that I learnt in a crafts workshop to build a himmeli : a himmeli is a construction in straw ([example image](http://fi.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himmeli)), a thread goes through the straw to keep it together. The knot I learnt was to join a new piece of thread, when you ran out of thread.

The knot I was taught was called "Kankurin Solmu" in Finnish (it translates to "Weaver's Knot"). I found the following diagram of the "Weaver's Knot" on [this Finnish web page](http://punomo.fi/kasityotekniikat/kankurinsolmu), but I just can't make out how it is built from the diagram.

Do you think that the knot in the photo I posted below corresponds to the so-called Weaver's Knot of the diagram at [that page](http://punomo.fi/kasityotekniikat/kankurinsolmu)? (Something doesn't seem quite right to me but I can't exactly remember the knot I was taught and I can't really make out the diagram).

Does the knot in the photo of my post seem viable as a knot to join thread?

[image]
<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

Comment: Can you tell us more about this knot? Have you found it in use somewhere or did you tie it yourself? It is very well possible that this knot has been discovered and discarded many times as unreliable or too hard to untie.

Comment: This knot would not be secure.  It isn't clear what purpose it serves.  It definitely isn't the "Weaver's knot" in your link.

Comment: I think its opinion based because it says: "Do you think that the knot in the photo I posted below corresponds to the so-called Weaver's Knot of the diagram at that page?"

Comment: @Isaac750 That question on its own indeed suggests to ask for opinions. However, there is only one true answer to this question, namely either 'yes, yours is the same knot' or 'no, this is a different knot' (reflected by the title) (and maybe a third and fourth, saying 'your knot is (/not) viable', based on the question in the last paragraph). Hence, it doesn't have the problems opinion-based questions have, and why they aren't allowed.

Answer (score 1):

The knot on the web page you posted looks like a basic square knot (aka [reef knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reef_knot)) to me, at least as far as the end result is concerned. (They're tying it upside-down for some reason, but they're ending up with two simple overhand knots, one right, one left, and that's gonna get you a square knot.) One of the square knot's main uses is to join two pieces of thread/yarn/string/rope, so it can certainly be used to tie in a new piece of thread while weaving.

What you're tying looks like maybe a strange configuration of a granny knot, which is not likely to stay put if you pull on the ends.

An actual "weaver's knot" does exist, but doesn't look like either your image or the website you linked to. It's also called a [sheet bend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheet_bend), if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

"A weaver's knot joins two threads together in a knot that will secure your threads and allow you to continue weaving." [*Source*](https://www.theweavingloom.com/weaving-techniques-the-weavers-knot/#:%7E:text=A%20weaver%27s%20knot%20joins%20two,allow%20you%20to%20continue%20weaving.)

This is not gonna work for you because  your using laces, this is meant to be used as something like  knitting, because you continue to make the knot over and over again.

However, your knot doesn't seem to match, I grabbed 2 laces and did what your image is showing, whenever i put pressure on it, it dissconnects.

Now, the link you're providing, shows 2 laces, each one with an "omega-like" logo tied together. So the answer is no. You're not doing it right. Try tying them like I said.

Comment: Maybe this helps, i don't know since they aren't putting the info requested in comment section.